# DateTimePicker Default Value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datetimepicker

I am using VB.Net 2008.

I have two DateTimePicker. The first has a default value 8/24/2017 1:35 PM (as it was created Aug. 24. The second one has the default value of what is the current date and time. I haven't set their default values in Properties.

It is just weird for me that they have different default values. Anyway, my desired value is the current date and time.

I have also experienced confusion on my previous project regarding DateTimePicker where it has always default time 1:32 PM where time should be disregarded. The format is "Short" and the default value is the current date w/o time.

Can anyone explain why it happens?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, a `DateTimePicker` contains the current date and time in its `Value` property unless you set it otherwise.  Why that should not be happening for one of your controls, I don't know. In that case though, I'd suggest simply deleting that control and adding a new one. Hopefully that will behave as expected.

There's no such thing as a `DateTimePicker` that "disregards" time. The `Value` property of a `DateTimePicker` is type `DateTime` and a `DateTime` ALWAYS has both a date component and a time component.  You can set the `Format` and optionally `CustomFormat` properties to show only the date, only the time or only some part thereof but that makes exactly zero difference to what's stored in the `Value` property.

Just like for any other `DateTime` value, if you want the `Value` of a `DateTimePicker` to represent just a date then you should zero the time.  If you want to use the current date without a time then use `DateTime.Today`, where `DateTime.Now` would get you the current time as well as the current date.  If you want to zero the time of any `DateTime` value, including the `Value` of a `DateTimePicker`, then you get its `Date` property.  Note that that does not affect the original value, but creates a new `DateTime` value with the same date and the time zeroed, e.g.

```
Dim selectedDate = myDateTimePicker.Value.Date
```

Note that `DateTime.Today` simply returns `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: It's not a case of being safe.  You use what is appropriate for the task.  If you want just a date then you use the `Date` property.  You do it because it is what is intended to be used in your scenario.  If you're using it "just in case" then I'd suggest that you haven't really designed your app properly.